# Keyboard not enabled until OS Win 10 starts. Unable to get into BIOS

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bootloader

I can't get into BIOS anymore. not sure which setting caused this but below are some changes i tried making in bios.

1) There is one more horrible thing happening is I hear 5 short beeps when PC starts. what does that mean?

2) I am not sure if should have XHCi handoff enabled? I suspect this is the setting leaving keyboard not enabled at boot time. I plug keyboard into USB 2.0 port.

3) I have changed windows 8/10 option from other OS to windows 8/10. not sure what value it adds but I have win 10 so thought of making this setting to win10

4) Not sure if i have set something like fast boot setting enabled. (Can this be a reason of keyboard not available during boot)

I don't see UEFI from windows 10 troubleshooting mode too
Is there a way to reset bios without removing the cmos battery

I want these things to be available atleast:
1) I want to use USB3.0 (I've windows 10, not sure if it requires XHCI handoff enable, and if this hadnoff causing boot keyboard active missing)
2) keyboards to be available during boot

Please suggest. I have below configuration:
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2
Processor i5-7400 7th gen
I've upgraded from win 8.1 to 10

Comment: According to http://www.website-go.com/artikel/beepcodes.php:  5 Beeps  | Processor error  |  Bad processor. Try to remove the processor and build it correctly again in.

Comment: But it doesn't beep when i just remove the battery and hardreset the bios

Comment: Well, you have asked: "There is one more horrible thing happening is I hear 5 short beeps when PC starts. what does that mean?" and I just found it out :)

Comment: I don't know how but i did a hard reset on bios and handoff enabled. Now i get what i want as mentioned in the question